# Fast way of comparing how "different" an int[] array is from another int[] array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, puzzle

I am trying to figure out a fast way to compare how "different" an int array is from another int array. I am going to use this function in a sliding puzzle solver. Here is an example:

```
{0,1,3,2,4,5,7,6,8}
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

Here, 4 elements (2,3,6,7) are out of order. Is there a fast way to determine this? I tried to think of a way, for instance a for loop, but that seems naive. Also, maybe using the following:

```
Arrays.hashCode(array1) - Arrays.hashCode(array2)
```

would be a way to determine that? 
Also, note that I am not necessarily trying to determine how *many* elements are out of order, but simply how different two arrays are since I am going to use this in A * heuristic.

Comment: Maybe something like the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)? It's a bit complex though, so it might not be quite what you're looking for/may require tweaking.

Comment: Since you are looking for a heuristic, something like a [Sørensen–Dice coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) could be adapted to work for this. 0 being no similarities and 1 being identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you could get much more efficient than a loop:

```
different = 0;
for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
  if (*a++ != *b++) { // walk through lists using 1 pointer each
    different++;
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is in Java

Comment: efficient yes. Correct? Not so much...

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie You're right, sorry about that. So much for efficiency :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int a[]= {0,1,3,2,4,5,7,6,8};
    int b[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int diff=0;
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    if(a[i]!=b[i])
    diff++;
    }
```